# Linear logic with storage preserving positives

Tags: lo.logic, linear-logic

Has anyone studied a version of linear logic in which the storage modality $!$ preserves the positive connectives and quantifiers $\otimes,\oplus,\exists$?  That is, such that we have $!(A\otimes B) = !A \otimes !B$ and $!(A\oplus B) = !A \oplus !B$ and $!\exists x. A = \exists x.!A$.  It seems that there ought to be a reasonable sequent calculus for such a theory, e.g. using a "modal context zone" as in [Girard's LU](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016800729390093S) or [Pfenning's LV](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.5019) enhanced with left rules that allow introducing $\otimes,\oplus,\exists$ in the modal zone.

Comment: That looks weird. Naively speaking, if you have $!(A \otimes B)$ you can produce any number of pairs $(a, b)$ so you will have the same amount of $A$'s and $B$'s. But with $!A \otimes !B$ you can have some number of $A$'s and some *other* number of $B$'s.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Well, actually I'm mainly interested in *affine* logic with this property, so that you could forget some of the $A$'s or the $B$'s.

Comment: But in general, yes, these are *additional* assumptions, not implied by the ordinary meaning of $!$.  Categorically speaking, they just say that a certain comonad is monoidal and cocontinuous, which doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: I don't think anyone has ever considered such a variant of linear logic.  For provability, maybe you don't even need "modal zones", it should be enough to consider modified sequent calculus rules like $$\frac{\Gamma,!^nA,!^nB\vdash C}{\Gamma,!^n(A\otimes B)\vdash C}$$ (with $!^n$ meaning $!\cdots !$ $n$ times, $n$ arbitrary) and similarly for $\oplus$ and $\exists$.  But this breaks cut-elimination...  Making cut-elimination work seems much less trivial and may involve enhanced "modal zones" like you say, but I don't see how.  By the way, good question!

Comment: One thing this reminds me of is Olivier Laurent's polarized linear logic, where weakening and contraction are allowed on any positive formula ($!A$ being considered positive for any $A$).